# In $P_2$, find the change-of-coordinates matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

In $P_2$, find the change-of-coordinates matrix from the basis $B=\{1-2t+t^2, 3-5t+4t^2, 2t+3t^2\}$ to the standard basis $C=\{1, t, t^2\}$. Then find the B-coordinate vector for $-1+2t$
I know how to do the first part. $P$ from $B$ to $C: \begin{bmatrix}1& 3& 0\\ -2 &-5& 2\\ 1& 4& 3\end{bmatrix}$. I do not know what the process is for finding the B coordinate vector though. Can someone give me a place to start for doing that?

Comment: The change of basis matrix is invertible and gives to the change of coordinates from $B$ to $C$. You know the coordinates for the vector $-1+2t$ with respect to the basis $C$, so multiply that vector by the inverse of the change of basis matrix you found.

Comment: So I found the inverse of the matrix to be [-23 -9 6, 8 3 -2, -3 -1 1]. When multiplied that matrix by [-1 2 0] I got [26 18 0] as my column vector. But the answer in my book says the answer is [5 -2 1]. Can anyone verify that that I have correctly done the inverse?

Comment: Megan: You have done the inverse correctly, but your multiplication is incorrect. See http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/multiply.aspx

Comment: @AlexWertheim Please consider converting your comments into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @mmm Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis vectors of B expressed with respect to the standard basis are:

$$v_1=(1,-2,1), v_2=(3,-5,4), v_3=(0,2,3)$$

Thus, the following matrix M, which colums are the component of the basis vectors B with respect to the standard basis:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1& 3& 0\\ -2 &-5& 2\\ 1& 4& 3\end{bmatrix}$$

represent the change of coordinates from the basis B to the standard basis C, that is:

$$v_C=Mv_B\implies v_B=M^{-1}v_C$$

where

$$M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-23& -9& 6\\ 8 &3& -2\\ -3& -1& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

represent the change of coordinates from the standard basis C to the basis B.

Thus for the vector $-1+2t=v_C=(-1,2,0)$ in the standard basis C, we obtain:

$$v_B=v_CM^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-23& -9& 6\\ 8 &3& -2\\ -3& -1& 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\ 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5\\ -2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

You can check indeed that:

$$v_C=5v_1-2v_2+v_3$$

Answer (score 0):

So, you have $P_{C \leftarrow B} = \begin{bmatrix}1&3&0\\-2&-5&2\\1&4&3\\ \end{bmatrix}$. So to get the second part, you need to row reduce the augmented matrix $ \begin{bmatrix} P_{C \leftarrow B} & [x]_{C} \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

So, what is $[x]_{C}$? Take $-1+2t$ and plug it in:
$$[x]_{C} = \begin{bmatrix} ?\\ ?\\ ?\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

If you don't see where the $0$ came from, think about the coefficient for $t^{2}$.

So now, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} P_{C \leftarrow B}& [x]_{C}\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&3&0&-1\\-2&-5&2&2\\1&4&3&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Now row reduce, and you'll have your answer.